# What is the trick to downloading a pkcs8 private key from Azure KeyVault, using Java Azure SDK?

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, certificate, azure-keyvault, azure-sdk

So, for reference, here is what I have working:

1. A call to a .pkcs12 stored in Certificates blade works:

   ```
      CertificateClient certificateClient = new CertificateClientBuilder()
              .vaultUrl(System.getenv("AzureWebJobsSecretStorageKeyVaultUri"))
              .credential(clientSecretCredential)
              .buildClient();
      KeyVaultCertificateWithPolicy certificate = certificateClient
        .getCertificate(certificateAzureName);
      CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
      ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(certificate
          .getCer());
      X509Certificate x509Certificate = (X509Certificate) certFactory
          .generateCertificate(inputStream);
      keyStore.setCertificateEntry(nonprodCertificateAlias, x509Certificate);
   ```
2. Also, a call to get the public cert chain, stored as a secret (similar to the above but without private key).   This works:

```
SecretClient secretClient = new SecretClientBuilder()
                    .vaultUrl(envUtil.getProperty(AppVar.AzureWebJobsSecretStorageKeyVaultUri))
                    .credential(clientSecretCredential)
                    .buildClient();
log.info("Created SecretClient.");
Objects.requireNonNull(secretClient, "Azure SecretClient is null. Could not
   be constructed.");
KeyVaultSecret secret = secretClient.getSecret(publicChainAzureName);
String encodedString = secret.getValue();
byte[] decodedCertChain = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedString);
....
Certificate certificate1 = certFactory
  .generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedCertChain));
keyStore.setCertificateEntry(nonprodCertificateAlias, certificate1);
```

BUT, I cannot get a download of a private key (in `pkcs8` pem format, & RSA) to work.   Here is the code that just gives me the error `Method threw 'java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException' exception:  Invalid key format` :

```
Certificate publicKeyChainCert = certFactory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedCertChainSecret));
                
//keyStore.setCertificateEntry(pubCertChainAlias, publicKeyChainCert);
KeyVaultSecret secretKey = secretClient.getSecret(privateKeyAzureName);
String encodedPrivateKey = secretKey.getValue();
byte[] decodedPrivateKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedPrivateKey);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
// next line throws this 
//  error: Method threw 'java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException' exception.
// : Invalid key format
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(decodedPrivateKey);
privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
keystore.setKeyEntry(pkCertAlias, privateKey, null, 
  new Certificate[]{publicKeyChainCert});
```

[image]

NOTE:  I used Keytool Explorer to export the .pkcs8 private key from my .pfx keystore.  I uploaded that secret into the "Secrets" blade of my KeyVault.   So, I assumed that downloading and base64 decode should get me back the exact same file but it appears it doesnt?

Answer (score 1):

When you create or import a PEM file (`application/x-pem-file`), the secret value is not base64-encoded. It's a raw ASCII string containing the PEM using `\n` for new lines.

My Java is rusty (some pun intended), but you should just be able to elide several of the middle lines of your example:

```java
Certificate publicKeyChainCert = certFactory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedCertChainSecret));
                
//keyStore.setCertificateEntry(pubCertChainAlias, publicKeyChainCert);
KeyVaultSecret secretKey = secretClient.getSecret(privateKeyAzureName);
String privateKey = secretKey.getValue();
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKey);
privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
keystore.setKeyEntry(pkCertAlias, privateKey, null, 
  new Certificate[]{publicKeyChainCert});
```

This is what I do in the Key Vault .NET `CertificateClient`, which provides a similar `DownloadCertificateAsync` method that conditions base64 decoding on the certificate policy content-type, which you can get either by evaluating the certificate policy or should be set in the managed secret's `contentType` property - either `application/x-pem-file` or `application/x-pkcs12`.